# How to convert JSON to array and get name,value?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a result as JSON string

```
[{"GROUP_MOD_ID":"G02","ADD":1,"EDIT":0,"DEL":1,"VIEW":null,"UP":1,"PRINT":null,"ADMIN":null,"MOD":null,"ADD-AD":null,"EDIT-AD":null,"DEL-AD":null,"VIEW-AD":null}]
```

Ok, I want to get name and value do something as

```
 public static bool Check(string group_mod_id)
    { 
         var obj = GroupModBus.GetGroupModFunc(group_mod_id);
         if (obj != "[]")
         {
            if (obj.Contains["ADD"]=="1")
            {
               //do something
                return true;
            }
         }
         else
             return false;
    }
```

It's get error `Error   1   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'`

NOTEs: In here dynamic data, not in a instance.Normally, if data in one instance, I can use like this

```
public class EXAMPLE
{
    public string ADD { get;set;}
    public string EDIT {get;set;}
    ///etc....
} 
///using  as 
if (obj.ADD =="1")
{
       //do something
       return true;
}
```

I think i should convert JSON string to array , then get name and get value .Do you think so ?

Comment: Why is this being done "by hand"? JSON is a serialization format which *should generally **not** be modified / accessed as text* - use (one of the many) libraries available to deal with it as an object graph.

Comment: Please notes, data is dynamic , not in a instance so i use as follow.

Comment: That's fine, use a library that allows derserilization to a Dictionay<..> or a JSONObject.

Comment: Why not use JSON.NET. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: At this point there is no clear problem in the post except "how to parse JSON" - which has quite good answer on SO already. Feel free to clarify your question why it is not duplicate or ask new question if some particular aspects of Json.Net are not clear (or if you have questions about another JSON parsing library).

Comment: I use `dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);
                string add = stuff.ADD;
                if (add == "1")
                {
                    //do something
                    return true;
                }`  But it's not work, error `'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'ADD'`

Comment: That's because DerserializeObject returns a JObject/JArray (see the documentation) and *not* a dynamic object *of* the data (the placement of `dynamic` in the line does *not* change the result of the method!). To use a 'dynamic object' instead of JArray/JObject access, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495 which explains the correct method to use and provides example code.

Comment: Well,I seen document `http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm` and try but it's not work. It's error `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1` . I use `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`